# how to access the secureTextEntry for further use?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios4

Hi I'm using the below code which includes the alertView containing UserID and Password field.

these UserID and Password are text field, i made password field as secure, but when i later want to access the data entered in password field, its showing no value in password field..

My code is

```
    self.loginPassword = [[ UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Login" message:@"Enter Valid UserID and Password\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
    //[self.loginPassword setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];

    self.userIDText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 80.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
    self.userIDText.text=@"";
    [self.userIDText setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.userIDText setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
    [self.userIDText setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
    [self.userIDText setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

    self.passwordField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0,115.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
    self.passwordField.text=@"";
    [self.passwordField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.passwordField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
    [self.passwordField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
    [self.passwordField setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

    [self.loginPassword addSubview:self.userIDText];
    [self.loginPassword addSubview:self.passwordField];
    self.passwordField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    [self.loginPassword setTag:2];
    [self.loginPassword show];
    [self.loginPassword release];
```

please suggest me some solution..

Comment: Why are you creating your own text fields instead of using the style of `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput`?

Comment: no iOS 4.3 will not support this.. i'm creating the subView to alertView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you.Just take a look at the code.

https://github.com/josecastillo/EGOTextFieldAlertView

Answer (score 2):

Create and In-built `UIAlertView`

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
// Define Alertview Type to Login&Password
[alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
// Set Delegate to access Input Value
[alert setDelegate:self];
// show it
[alert show];
```

set `Delegate` in you `interface` (.h file) `UIAlertViewDelegate`
Implement This delegate method in your `implementation` (.m file)

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // Access your Username & Password from alertview and store them for further use.
    NSString *username = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    NSString *password = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:1] text];

    NSLog(@"Username : %@ , Password : %@",username, password);
}
```

Comment: i know this solution.. as its commented in my code.. but this is not supported in iOS4.3.. so i used above formate..

Comment: it is supported in IOS 5.0 but you need do something what i did with my code, you can access textField Value as i did in example

Comment: i have used this formate before.. but requirement is for iOS 4.3.. so i cant use this..

Comment: you have done correct coding ,you can add textfield in you alertview as you did, but to access the value you have to use my code as i did in delegate method

Comment: ya thanks for your answer but this link is better helpful : " https://github.com/josecastillo/EGOTextFieldAlertView " as suggested by RJR..